# Regarding preorder tree traversal

Tags: c++

I have written the following code snippet for recursive Binary Tree Preorder Traversal:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
private:
    std::vector<int> myVec;
public:
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root==NULL)
            return vector<int>();

        myVec.push_back(root->val);
        preorderTraversal(root->left);
        preorderTraversal(root->right);

        return myVec;
    }
};
```

While this code runs and produces the expected output, I am not totally sure if this is correct; because when I call `preorderTraversal(root->left);` and `preorderTraversal(root->right);` I am not using the values that they return (`vector<int>`s).  So,

1. Is this correct?
2. If no, then how can I rectify this code?

Comment: Try it with debugger and check when appropriate values are added into the vector.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan, my question is not about _when they are added_; in fact, my question is, _is it right when they are added_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct if you call it once. If not, `myVec` vector is not cleared.

In fact, each call to `preorderTraversal`, except the top one and path from it to the left, return some intermediate state which doesn't make much sense. If I were you, I would refactor this code to hide the intermediate value inside the class:

```
class Solution {
private:
    std::vector<int> myVec;

    void traverse(TreeNode* root) {
        if (root == NULL)
            return;

        myVec.push_back(root->val);
        preorderTraversal(root->left);
        preorderTraversal(root->right);
    }

public:
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        myVec.clear();
        traverse(root);
        return myVec;
    }
};
```

Comment: Cool; you have done it in a nice way.  So, just to be clear, can we say in general, that it is not _necessary_ for us to use the values that a recursive function call returns?

Comment: @RameshSippy Sure. We live in a free world and may and may not use the return values of recursive calls.

Comment: This is not reentrant and not thread safe. Why use the data member at all?

Comment: @n.m., sorry, could you kindly elaborate?  I didn't get you.  I need to store the preorder nodes in a vector to be returned later.

Comment: You only need it to exist while running `preorderTraversal`, thus the natural place for it to live is inside `preorderTraversal` as an automatic variable.